# Why does IE11 drop this margin setting when the font resizes on hover?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

This is an odd bug that I've encountered. In IE11, it will set the top margin correctly at first, until I hover over a link that re-sizes. The moment I do that, the top margin seems to disappear, only to reappear if I adjust the width of the window (or frame).

```css
#upper_menu {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
}
.container_full {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.container_12 {
  width: 92%;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
.container_12 .grid_10 {
  width: 81.333%;
}
#state_container ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 8.25%;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#state_container ul li {
  display: inline;
}
#state_container ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .2em 1em;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  color: #999999;
}
#state_container ul li a:hover {
  font-size: 1.55em;
  color: #000;
}
#state_container ul li .selected_state {
  font-size: 1.55em;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="upper_menu" class="container_full">
  <div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_10">
      <div id="state_container">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="selected_state">Connecticut</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">New&nbsp;Hampshire</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">New&nbsp;Jersey</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">New&nbsp;York</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(When running the snippet, use full screen to be able to resize the window, and view the issue in IE11)

I've simplified it as much as I can without losing the issue, and because of that I've determined that it seems to have something to do with the outermost div, specifically the `overflow:hidden;` located in `.container_full`, but I cannot just remove that as it is necessary for other parts of the page. It may be related to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251303/how-can-i-work-around-this-ie11-layout-bug-related-to-table-cell-text-decoratio), but I'm not certain that it is in fact the same issue.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this happens, and does anyone know of a workaround that doesn't involve removing `overflow:hidden;`?

Comment: you are using any "normalize" CSS ?

Comment: @LeandroRuel I'm unsure what that is, so I'd have to say probably not. I'll look up what it is though.

Comment: @LeandroRuel Do you mean a css reset? If so, then yes, I am.

Comment: cool, your reset have this > `*{box-sizing: border-box; }` ?

Comment: @LeandroRuel It did not, but adding it made no difference.

Comment: Looks like an IE bug to me. Try removing `margin-top` from `#state_container ul` and adding it as `padding-top` on `#state_container`.

Comment: Depending on which browsers you need to support, replacing `%` with [`vh`](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) might be an option. http://jsfiddle.net/hqNXg/4/

Comment: i'm using Ubuntu, sorry, can't test now.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Changing the margin to padding as you suggested worked perfectly. Plus I learned about vw/vh. If you post your solution as an answer I will accept it (and +1 it when I have the rep to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an IE bug to me. Removing `margin-top` from `#state_container ul` and adding it as `padding-top` on `#state_container` should work around the problem:

```
#state_container {
    padding-top:8.25%;
}
#state_container ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hqNXg/5/

Alternatively, depending on which browsers you need to support, replacing `%` with `vh` might be an option:

```
#state_container ul {
    margin:0;
    margin-top:8.2vh;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hqNXg/4
http://caniuse.com/#search=vh
http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units