# Is there a workaround for the IE11 table cell padding bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-11

We are having problems displaying an image in a css table cell (#content3) with relative padding. This ONLY occurs in IE11 and displays normally in all other browsers!

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">    
    <div id="container">    
        <div id="content1"></div>
        <div id="content2"></div>        
        <div id="content3"><img src="an-image.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{width:95%;}
#container{display:table; width:100%;}
#content1{display:table-cell; width:28%; background:url(anotherimage.jpg);}
#content2{display:table-cell; width:47%; background:url(yetanotherimage.jpg);}
#content3{display:table-cell; width:20%; position:relative; padding-bottom:20%; height:0px;}
#content3 img{height:100%; width:100%; position:absolute:0; left:0;}
```

This would seem to be a bug which has been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251303/how-can-i-work-around-this-ie11-layout-bug-related-to-table-cell-text-decoratio)

However, none of the solutions offered work for us.

Interestingly, the image appears as soon as we resize the browser window manually.

Are there any CSS or JS/jQuery workarounds for this?

Many thanks in advance for any help on this!

Comment: I'm probably going to get kicked by someone for this, but have you considered using a `<table>` for better compatibility? More sensibly, what about `display:inline-block`?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: as I mentioned, the solutions offered to the question you refer to do NOT resolve the problem for us. Our code is also different to that posed in the other question. Please remove the duplicate entry so we can get some decent responses to this problem which - according to the MS bug entry - is causing several people difficulties.